# Crash when using delete [] to delete a pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The code I'm using to make output of pTemp:

```
if (m_pTImgFrame != NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nFrameNumber; i++)
    {
        TImage* pTemp = (TImage*)m_pTImgFrame[i];
        if (pTemp != NULL)
        {
            TCHAR buffer[256] = { 0 };
            _stprintf_s(buffer, 256, _T("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n"), 
                pTemp->attrib,
                pTemp->h,
                pTemp->pitch,
                pTemp->w,
                pTemp->data[0],
                pTemp->data[1], 
                pTemp->data[2], 
                pTemp->data[3]);
            OutputDebugString(buffer);

            delete[] pTemp;
            m_pTImgFrame[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete []m_pTImgFrame;
    m_pTImgFrame = NULL;
}
```

The **origin** code which still **crashes**

```
if (m_pTImgFrame != NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nFrameNumber; i++)
    {
        BYTE* pTemp = (BYTE*)m_pTImgFrame[i];
        if (pTemp != NULL)
        {
            delete[] pTemp;
            m_pTImgFrame[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete []m_pTImgFrame;
    m_pTImgFrame = NULL;
}
```

declaration of variables:

```
typedef unsigned int        UINT;
typedef struct _TImage
{
    int  w;         
    int  h;         
    int  pitch;     
    int  attrib;    
    unsigned char data[4];  
} TImage;

UINT        m_nFrameNumber;     
UINT*       m_pnFrameDelay;     
TImage**    m_pTImgFrame;

PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih; 
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
    DWORD      biSize;
    LONG       biWidth;
    LONG       biHeight;
    WORD       biPlanes;
    WORD       biBitCount;
    DWORD      biCompression;
    DWORD      biSizeImage;
    LONG       biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG       biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD      biClrUsed;
    DWORD      biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, FAR *LPBITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Allocation:

```
    m_pTImgFrame = new TImage*[1];
    m_pTImgFrame[0] = (TImage*)new BYTE[sizeof(TImage) - 4 + 4 * width * pbih->biHeight];
    m_pTImgFrame[0]->attrib = imageAttrib8888;
    m_pTImgFrame[0]->w = width;
    m_pTImgFrame[0]->h = pbih->biHeight;
    m_pTImgFrame[0]->pitch = 4 * width;
    LOG(_T("32width=%d, height=%d"), width, pbih->biHeight);
    for(j=pbih->biHeight-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        int indexDst = (pbih->biHeight-j-1) * width * 4;
        //int indexSrc = j * pbih->biWidth * 4;
        int indexSrc = j * ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * cClrBits +31) & ~31) /8/*bmpInfo.bmWidthBytes*/;
        for(i=0; i< width; i++)
        {
            m_pTImgFrame[0]->data[indexDst++] = lpBits[indexSrc++];
            m_pTImgFrame[0]->data[indexDst++] = lpBits[indexSrc++];
            m_pTImgFrame[0]->data[indexDst++] = lpBits[indexSrc++];
            m_pTImgFrame[0]->data[indexDst++] = 255;
            indexSrc++;
        }
    }
```

The code will crash when run the line
`delete [] pTemp` if the m_nFrameNumber is 1 (I only saw the crash happened when it is 1 but I'm not sure);The output of each value of the pTemp is correct, so why it crashes ?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Posting images of code is not good. Post code.

Comment: If you delete some memory you must have newed it, but I can't see any new in your code.

Comment: @RSahu I post the image of code because there is an auto windows so the value of variables will be shown on it just before run the crash line. I think it is far more better than the pure code to anyone use visual studio.

Comment: It would be better to have code we can copy/paste and a MCVE

Comment: **DON'T POST PICTURES OF YOUR CODE.**  Post the actual code itself.  I can't cut and paste the relevant sections into an answer.  So yes, I have an answer, but you need to post the code as text.  Also, please show where you are allocating m_pTImgFrame and the individual elements within it.

Comment: Show the code that allocates m_pTImgFrame and the elements of that array.  What are their types?

Comment: @selbie Have updated

Answer (score 0):

*The code will crash when run the line `delete [] pTemp` if the `m_nFrameNumber` is* ***`1`***

Given what you just said and that the allocation is as follows:

`m_pTImgFrame = new TImage*[1];`

The only valid index of `m_pTImgFrame` is `0` because you only allocate the array to be of size `1`.  Trying to access `m_pTImgFrame[1]` is undefined behavior.

Second, your new operator needs to match your delete operator for both type and scalar.

You allocated as a byte array:

```
m_pTImgFrame[0] = (TImage*)new BYTE[sizeof(TImage) - 4 + 4 * width * pbih->biHeight];
```

Therefor the correct way to deallocate the element is like this:

```
BYTE* allocation = (BYTE*)m_pTImgFrame[0];
delete [] allocaiton;
```

This is wrong:

```
    TImage* pTemp = (TImage*)m_pTImgFrame[i];
    if (pTemp != NULL)
    {
        ...
        delete[] pTemp; // deleting as an array of TImage, when it should be deleted as an array of bytes
    }
```

Unrelated tangent based on yoru code - It's not necessary to check for NULL before calling delete. Always has been safe to say `delete NULL`. Always will be.

Comment: Thanks in advance, the BYTE* casting is used in original code which crashed first, so I rewrite the code to output the value of `pTemp`. The m_nFrameNumber  is 1 can not let the i be 1, so m_pTImgFrame[0] is safety I think.

Comment: Finally, it is caused by using dll compiled by vc6 in vs2015 project.